# Centering a text in SVG

Tags: svg.js

How can I center a text in a circle? My structure is this: `<g><circle ...</><text ...>...</text></g>`

I already know this technique: `<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" width="100%"><g><circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%"/><text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dy="0.3em"></text></g></svg>`but this is not usable in svg.js.

I tried it with bbox, but the text is not really centered.

Any better ideas?

Edit:

Here is my code:

```js
let dot = draw.group();

let _dot = dot.circle(20).move(pos._x-10, pos._y-10);

let lab = dot.plain(i.toString());

let bA = _dot.bbox();
let bB = lab.bbox();

lab.move(bA.x+(bA.width-bB.width)/2,
    bA.y+(bA.height-bB.height)/2);
```

The result is this: https://i.ibb.co/FWbvbF2/dot.png

Comment: I dont see any svg.js code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I added my code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a center method to position a shape by its center:

```js
circle.center(20, 20)
text.center(20, 20)
```

However, you can use your method with svg.js, too. Just set the attributes you need with `attr()`